# Eclipse does not run my application

Tags: java, eclipse

Its a weird problem I am completely puzzled.

My application was running properly. Once I tried to re-run it without even changing a single line it did not run anymore.

It shows nothing special in console but shows HTTP Status 404 and the message says 
"The requested resource (/MyProject/) is not available."

I am using Eclipse, and tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with Eclipse where my program is running from a previous launch and gives an error when trying to launch it again.  If this is the case, you have to stop the previous run and launch a new run.

Comment: Yes I stopped the previous run and ran it again but still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean and republish your application on the tomcat server?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes I have cleaned, publish and restart the tomcat but does not run the app yet.